# What first aid can be done for Crab Bite?

Tags: hiking, first-aid

I occasionally hike in the Sahyadri ranges in Maharashtra (India).
During the rainy season there are a lot of crabs on the trail.
In case the crab bites, what are the first aid steps that can be taken?

Comment: I think you mean "pinch", you want first aid treatment for a crab pinch. It's hard to get bit by an animal that wears its teeth inside it's stomach.

Comment: Crabs have teeth in their stomach!? I'm going to have to give this a google lol

Comment: @NateWengert Ya, they have what's called a gastric mill, it's pretty weird.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- First control the bleeding with gauze or a cloth and light pressure
  Elevate the foot
- Clean with soap and water
- Apply an antiseptic
  You can get single packs
- Bandage/bandaid(plaster) if necessary

If they latch onto a toe they could break or sprain it. If so you can tape two toes together.

Comment: Yup. Crabs are not poisonous (as far as I know?), so it's a lot like any other dirty wound (a dog bite, a rusty nail wound...)

Comment: Come on down vote what is the problem?

Comment: I don't understand a down vote either. It would be great if the person would explain it, or if someone else might explain what they think could have happened. Thanks!

Comment: Only edit I would make is Bandage/Bandaid(plaster) if necessary :)

Comment: @Aravona Plaster in the field?  Are you assuming a crab could crush a foot?

Comment: @Paparazzi Not at all, the reason it was in brackets was because some people call band-aids plasters, ie, UK, it was a clarification as some people may not know what a band-aid is as it's an americanism.

Comment: @Aravona How does bandage not cover it?

Comment: @Paparazzi because it could be excessive and a plaster / band-aid is simpler and different to apply for smaller cases? Terminologies in first aid can be important.

Answer (score 2):

Crabs are scavengers, so their pincers are always to be considered evil sources of infection. You can use fluoride (if you act promptly); find the mouthwash with the highest fluoride content, and force it into a cut/wound with a syringe. Needle not required. After 5 minutes, rinse the wound with sterilized water and apply a proper bandage. If you have not brought mouthwash, you can use toothpaste, which can be easily diluted with sterilized water.

Be aware that fluoride is not intended for use inside wounds, so the wound *must* be rinsed with water.

Also, liquor with >=35-40% alcohol concentration will kill bacteria quite well.

India’s rural areas are notorious for their lack of proper and prompt healthcare, so you’d be wise to pack blisters with a wide-spectrum antibiotic as well. Similar to the fluoride, you can create a fast-acting antibacterial solution by extracting the powder from the capsules, mixing them with room-temperature sterilized water, and applying a thin paste to the cut/wound - then wrap a bandage around it. Simply eating a capsule will not bring a high enough concentration of antiobiotic to the wound.